# Selenium return empty images after few images

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am working with selenium and I want to get to images. The problem is that the selenium works up to 21 images and after that, it returns empty URLs like below.

```
1 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19230307.jpg?preset=dept
2 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/18097354.jpg?preset=dept
3 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19230311.jpg?preset=dept
4 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19234200.jpg?preset=dept
5 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/17307902.jpg?preset=dept
6 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19305650.jpg?preset=dept
7 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19060456.jpg?preset=dept
8 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/18295767.jpg?preset=dept
9 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19102600.jpg?preset=dept
10 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19230297.jpg?preset=dept
11 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/16181113.jpg?preset=dept
12 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19101047.jpg?preset=dept
13 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19150290.jpg?preset=dept
14 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19042244.jpg?preset=dept
15 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19230329.jpg?preset=dept
16 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19101040.jpg?preset=dept
17 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/17000870.jpg?preset=dept
18 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19100952.jpg?preset=dept
19 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19183658.jpg?preset=dept
20 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/19102243.jpg?preset=dept
21 :  https://photo.venus.com/im/18176590.jpg?preset=dept
22 :  data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
23 :  data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
24 :  data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
25 :  data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
26 :  ...
```

I even used time sleep, but it has not worked. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here is also my code:

```
url = 'https://www.venus.com/products.aspx?BRANCH=7~63~'
driver.get(url)

product_container_ls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product-container')

for prd in product_container_ls:
    # Finding elements of images by class name
    image_lm = prd.find_element_by_class_name('main')

    # The url to image
    image_url = image_lm.get_attribute('src')
    print(image_id, ': ', image_url)

    # Image Path
    image_path = os.path.join(directory, f'{image_name}.jpg')

    # Getting and saving the image
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, image_path)

    image_id += 1
    time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Get to images where? What is this output from? You just provided a list of URL outputs from your code, but we have no context for what your code is doing, what it looks like, or what page you are trying to automate.

Comment: To get the images I need the URL of each image. I added my code, please take a look at it!

Comment: item 22 (and others) is not empty image but embeded image. Did you try to decode it to `png`?

Comment: BTW: some pages use "lazy loading" and they load image (they put correct URL to load it) when you scroll page. Maybe you have to scroll page and JavaScript will put correct URL to image.

Comment: @furas Exactly, after image 21 they use "main lazy" as the class name while before that the class name is "main". What is your solution?

Comment: as I said - you have to scroll page.

Comment: Since there is lazy loading, you might need to scrape the `data-original` value seeing as that is what is used for the eventual `src`

Comment: I checked HTML and every "lazy" image has `data-original=` with link to loaded image - use it.

Comment: @furas I am new to this stuff. Where can I read about "lazy loading"?

Comment: `lazy loading` is not standard element in JavaScript. You would have to search in Google tutorials, articles or JavaScript's modules (ie. [lazyload](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload)). Different modules may use different variables to keep original path.

Comment: @furas I have one more question. If you go to the link that I shared and click on one of the images you can see more images. I want to download those images. Should I use a sperate driver for downloading those images or I can download them using the same driver?

Comment: You can use the same driver but first get all urls to images (as strings) on current page. If you keep them as WebElements and you change page then it will lost access to these elements. Frankly, I don't know if you can create another driver - probably Selenium can use only one driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for the attribute of `data-original` rather than the `src` since this how they are lazy loading the images. I modified the following variable and got all the images

`image_url = image_lm.get_attribute('data-original')`

Here is a sample of my print out for that variable:

```
https://photo.venus.com/im/18235739.jpg?preset=dept
https://photo.venus.com/im/19034244.jpg?preset=dept
https://photo.venus.com/im/17199949.jpg?preset=dept
https://photo.venus.com/im/19121197.jpg?preset=dept
https://photo.venus.com/im/18235918.jpg?preset=dept
https://photo.venus.com/im/18366410.jpg?preset=dept
```

Comment: I have one more question. If you go to the link that I shared and click on one of the images you can see more images. I want to download those images.  Should I use a sperate driver for downloading those images or I can download them using the same driver?

Comment: You might have to use a different process. Once you have the list of urls you could download them without having to navigate with Selenium. I know I have done this before but I don’t have the code right now.